# Three.js examples - how to approach them

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've been learning Three.js and I came across these examples by Nat Geo.  I was wondering if anyone knows how to make the scroll wheel control the progression of the animation and how it is mixed with their website's regular look... It seems like in the first example that the webgl element is in the background with the normal html elements floating over it, but I don't understand how they timed the animations to it.

If anyone has insight on how these were created I'd appreciate it!

https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2017/09/cassini-saturn-nasa-3d-grand-tour/#enceladus

https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2016/11/exploring-mars-map-panorama-pictures/

Answer (score 1):

[Scrolling is a browser event](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/).

I did not look at the linked pages specifically, instead I'll describe a more generic scenario.

Once you understand how the event works, it's easy to see that one could track how far one has scrolled on the current page. Look at the scroll distance as a kind of trigger, where once you pass distance X, then something specific should happen.

Consider the below snippet, where crossing certain thresholds changes the background color of the button:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("myButton");
var position = 0;

function scrollHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.wheelDeltaY > 0 || position !== 0) {
    position += e.wheelDeltaY;
  }
  console.log(position);
  if (position < 500) {
    button.style.background = "";
  }
  if (position > 500) {
    button.style.background = "red";
  }
  if (position > 1000) {
    button.style.background = "green";
  }
}

button.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHandler);
button.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHandler);
```

```html
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="BUTTON!" />
```

Run the code snippet, then hover over the button and scroll up/down.

Answer (score 0):

For animations, the *time* is what you need.

```
var uniTime = gl.getUniformLocation( prg, "uniTime" );
gl.uniform1f( uniTime, time );
```

But you can cheat and use the amount of scrolling in place of real time.
For instance, if you need that the full scroll of your screen represents 7 seconds, you can use this bit of code in your animation loop:

```
time = 7000 * screen.scrollTop / screen.scrollHeight;
```

Here is a living example: https://jsfiddle.net/m1a9qry6/23/